# SSIS multiple table export

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

Suppose,I have to export two tables **Table_1** and **Table_2** to a location **C:\drive**

The generated file names should be **Table_1.txt** and **Table_2.txt**

My derived SSIS design:-
[image]

Variables are:- 
[image]

From Get Table List task I am retrieving list of two tables.

In the foreach container I want to extract value for `TableName` and `FileName` variables,using those Scrip task code will give desired output.

What should I do to extract value for `TableName` and `FileName` in the foreach container

Comment: There are many examples online on how to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/ http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/loop-through-ado-recordset-in-ssis.html

Comment: What does this even mean?:   `using those Scrip task code will give desired output.`     And what exactly does `Get Table List` do?